# Problem on eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let A be real square matrix of order $n \geq 2$. Then show that:
>
> A. if $A^3 - I$ is singular, then $1$ is eigenvalue of $A$
>
> B. if $A$ is singular, then $I+2A+A^2$ has eigenvalue $1$

My attempt: $|A^3 - I| = |A - I| |A^2 + A + I|$. Given that this determinant is zero, A cannot equal the identity $I,$ so $|A^2 + A + I| = 0$. Can you please help me?

Comment: Why $A \neq I$? Even if $A \neq I$, you cannot conclude $\det(A^2+A+I) = 0$ since it is possible to have $\det(A-I) = 0$.

Comment: Right, my mistake.

Comment: In fact $\det(A-I) = 0$ is what you have to show. You should try to do the other way round: $\det(A^2+A+I) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is wrong. Consider
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}) & -\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})\\
\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3}) & \cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Then $A^3 - I = O$ is singular but the rotational matrix $A$ does not have a real eigenvalue.

I did not really write down a proof for the following, but I think if some additional assumptions are made, then the statement can be made correct and the proof will be straightforward, namely:

> If $A$ is diagonalizable with all its eigenvalues being real, and $A^3 - I$ is singular, then $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

For the second statement, if $A$ is singular, then there exists $v \neq 0$ such that $Av = 0$ which implies $(A+I)v = v$ and therefore 
$$(A^2+2A+I)v = (A+I)^2v = (A+I)((A+I)v) = (A+I)v = v$$
which show that $A^2+2A+I$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Please read the edit. You may be interested in trying to prove the modified statement.